# 'Disks' app can't remember disabling SMART check

Tags: smart

I have a secondary drive (a HDD) that has a SMART flag on for "imminent catastrophe". I just want to keep there dup info from external drivers (never new files) because it says that since some years ago, but has no bad sectors ever. However, I have a problem.

Ubuntu tells me when I boot, with a desktop message, that one unit is going to fail soon. Ok, I go to disks --> select the drive --> SMARTS tests & stuff (sorry, I have Ubuntu in Spanish, can't say the exact English translation) --> and disable the SMART switch.

But when I restart Ubuntu, SMART is enable again for that drive, and the message appears again. Does anyone knows how can I fix this, so it will stop telling me that?

Comment: Edit your question and show me the **SMART Data** window for that secondary HDD. It's scrollable, so it might take two screenshots. Do you have good backups of the data on that drive? Have you made any attempts to fix the problems with that drive? Also show me a screenshot of `gparted` for that drive.

Comment: You can permanently set smart attributes in `/etc/smartd.conf`, your disk have probably past the intended life period. Think `-f` turns it off.

Comment: Thanks heynnema, but there is nothing that anybody can do for the health of that drive. Here you have those screenshots: https://postimg.cc/9wyCJXPN https://postimg.cc/BLxVzjyD

It seems that this series has a factory fault. I've watched the number of bad sectors for a while after that flag is on, but never increased.

And I never put new info in that drive: everything is backed up.

Comment: bac0n, I'm afraid that file doesn't exist (I've tried opening it with gedit with copy-paste and looked for it in /etc). I have Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Could it be in somewhere else?

Comment: So... no one? No ideas about how to "tell" Ubuntu to stop reminding that?